# Where can I find a pluggable blog app for Django?

Tags: python, django, blogs, django-apps

Where can I find an open source pluggable blog app for Django?

It should support:

- RSS/Atom
- Comments
- the built-in Django authentication system
- Markdown (optional)
- Akismet or other spam protection (optional)

Plus, I'd like to have to ability to embed the blog front page into another page, maybe in another app.

I'd like it to be as simple as possible - no unneccsary features, and 2-3 apps max.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [**`django packages'`**](http://djangopackages.com/grids/g/blogs/) grid for blog applications.

I would find find one that looks close to what you are looking for and edit it to fit your needs. That's the great thing about django, the ability to customize.

Answer (score 1):

I've used Django Basic Blog as the base, and customized it to suit my needs, it is part of [Django Basic Apps](https://github.com/nathanborror/django-basic-apps)

Answer (score 1):

[django-zinnia-blog](https://github.com/Fantomas42/django-blog-zinnia) has RSS feeds, traceback/pingback and comments via django-comments. You can use signals to have [your comments checked via akismet](http://sciyoshi.com/2008/8/using-akismet-djangos-new-comments-framework/). To support markdown you can use [a template filter](http://www.freewisdom.org/projects/python-markdown/Django).

Answer (score 0):

[Eleven django blog engines you should know](http://blog.montylounge.com/2010/02/10/eleven-django-blog-engines-you-should-know/)